# Surveyjs with magento2

Tags: magento2, php, requirejs

I am integrating survey js with Magento 2. Referring the below link.

https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library/?id=Add-Survey-into-your-Web-Page

But facing an issue:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Survey is not defined

**Anyone has an idea about it.**

Comment: could you please share solution here ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your js file with below code:

```
require(['jquery'],function(){
//js file code
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Make sure the braces are correctly coded.

Comment: Tried same, but it gives error :                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StylesManager' of undefined

Comment: Issue resolved by adding dependencies in require-config.js